# Declare Variables In Groovy FOR Loop

Tags: groovy

I want to create a loop in Groovy, that declares two objects. Then sets these two objects to the JSON values produced from Terraform command.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
   def "instance_" + i
   "instance_" + i = terraform output -json EC2Instance_IDs | jq -r '.[0]'
   println instance_ + i
}
```

I've been getting errors, such as:

```
(instance_ + i) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line:
```

and,

```
unexpected token: instance_ @ line 52, column 45. def instance_
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this:

```
0.upto(1) { i ->
   this."instance_$i" = "Fred $i"
   println this."instance_$i"
}
```

Running the above snippet will give this output:

```
Fred 0
Fred 1
```

Or you could use a collection.